# Mongoose reports successful writing, nothing in the database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

The mongoose success callback is running but nothing is appearing in my db, when I interact with Mongo via the console.

Can anyone assist for why nothing is appearing in the db?

app.js

```
var express = require('express')
  , routes = require('./routes')
  , user = require('./routes/user')
  , http = require('http')
  , path = require('path')
  , mongoose = require('mongoose');

var app = express();

var TimesheetsController = require(__dirname + '/controllers/timesheets');
var UsersController = require(__dirname + '/controllers/users');

app.configure(function(){
  app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'jade');
  app.use(express.favicon());
  app.use(express.logger('dev'));
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(express.cookieParser('your secret here'));
  app.use(express.session());
  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(require('stylus').middleware(__dirname + '/public'));
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
});

app.configure('development', function(){
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
});

app.get('/', routes.index);

app.get('/timesheets', TimesheetsController.list);
app.post('/timesheets', TimesheetsController.add);
app.get('/users', UsersController.list)

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log("Express server listening on port " + app.get('port'));
});
```

timesheet.js controller

```
var TimesheetsModel = require('../models/timesheets');

var TimesheetsController = {

    list : function(req, res){
        TimesheetsModel.listTimesheetsByUser(function(){res.render('timesheets/index', { title: 'Timesheets',timesheets: {} });});
    },
    add : function(req, res){
        TimesheetsModel.newTimesheet(10, req.body, function(err){ 
                                                        if(err){
                                                            res.json({'message':'failed.'})
                                                        }else{
                                                            res.json({'message':'success!'})
                                                        }; 
                                                    });
    }
}

module.exports = TimesheetsController;
```

timesheet.js model

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
  , Schema = mongoose.Schema
  , ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId;

var db = mongoose.createConnection('localhost', 'timetracker');

var TimesheetSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  'date': Date,
  'lines': [ {any: Schema.Types.Mixed} ],
  'user_id': ObjectId
});

var Timesheet = db.model('Timesheet', TimesheetSchema)


// Timesheet.virtual('id')
//   .get(function() {
//     return this._id.toHexString();
//   });

// Timesheet.pre('save', function(next) {
//   this.keywords = extractKeywords(this.data);
//   next();
// }); 


mongoose.model('Timesheet', Timesheet);

TimesheetsModel = {
    listTimesheetsByUser : function(callback){
    console.log('listing timesheets');
    callback();

    },

  newTimesheet : function(user,data,callback){

    var date = data.date;
    var lines = data.lines;
    var u = user;

    console.log(lines);

    var ts = new Timesheet({ "date": Date.now(),"lines":lines, "user_id":u });

    ts.save(function (err) {
        if (err) callback(err);
        console.log('adding new timesheet'); //this is output
        callback();
    });
  }
};

module.exports = TimesheetsModel
```

Comment: Where is the code where you're inserting into the database?

Comment: What collection name are you checking in the mongo console?

Comment: I'm saving to the db near the bottom of the timesheet model. `ts.save(function (err) {
        if (err) callback(err);
        console.log('adding new timesheet'); //this is output
        callback();
    });`

Comment: I've checked in all of the collections in my console. I thought it might be writing someplace funny so I dropped all of the dbs. In the console for mongod I am NOT seeing a record written to the db, but the success callback is called anyway.

Comment: FYI, you're 'adding new timesheet' output will always display regardless if there is an error or not because you're not returning from the function after your error callback. Are you always seeing the JSON `{"message": "success!"}`?

Comment: Yep, it's coming through as well.

Comment: Why are you calling
"mongoose.model('Timesheet', Timesheet)"?
Have you tried with that line commented out?

Answer (score 1):

A couple of issues - I am guessing from your code that you are getting an error. You need to fix a couple of things:

a) return with the callback:

```
 if (err) return callback(err);
 console.log('adding new timesheet'); //this is output
 callback();
```

b) I suspect the error has to do with you passing '10' as a user ID. Your schema is set to want an ObjectId (24 chars) so will fail with this.